# How to determine denominators and numerators when converting units

Tags: fractions, unit-of-measure

How do I determine which unit of measure should go into a denominator and which to go into the numerator? An example of converting 60kms/ph to ms (meters per sec) is:

$$\frac{60km}{1hr}\:=\:\frac{60km}{1hr}\:\cdot \frac{1000m}{1km}\:\cdot \frac{1hr}{3600s}\:$$

Looking at it, I can see they went opposites, like km as the numerator so the next is a denominator and the final fraction is the denominator from the first as the numerator.

Why or how did the $\frac{1000m}{1km}\:$ become the second fraction? Such as, why is it not $\frac{1km}{1000m}\:$?

What knowledge do I need to know to use this for any unit conversion (such as $2.7gcm^-3$ to $kg m^-3$) rather than just guessing by the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Units act just like variables.  If you divide $m^3$ by $m^2$ you get $m$.  In your example there is one copy of $km$ and $hr$ each in the numerator and denominator on the right, so the total exponent is $0$ for both and they need not appear on the left.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I found it hard to put the words out originally, but I have edited it since your response. I was confused on why the km was first the numerator and then it was the denominator when multiplying across? Is that the fraction rule thing where you cross multiply to eliminate like terms/variables?

Comment: Just like clearing denominators, you are multiplying by $1$ in various forms.  $\frac {1000 g}{1 kg}=1$ so you can multiply by it any time you want.  You choose the forms of $1$ to get the units from what you have to what you want.  The last two terms on the right in your equation are forms of $1$.  A good way to figure out what to do is to express everything in units of length, mass, and time.  If you have $1 \frac {furlong}{fortnight}$ and want $\frac {cm}{sec}$ you look up how many cm in a furlong and how many sec in a fortnight.